# How to count value greater than or equal to 0.5 continuous for 5 or greater than 5 rows python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I am trying to count values in column x greater than or equal to 0.5 for continuous for 5 times or greater. i also need to use groupby function for my data .

i used this function work fine , but this function can not count continuous occurrence of value  , its just count all values greater than or equal 0.5

```
data['points_greater_0.5'] = data[abs(data['x'])>=0.5].groupby(['y','z','n'])['x'].count()
```

but i want to count if greater than or equal to 0.5 value occurs continuous for 5 times or more

Comment: Can you provide an example of input DataFrame and of the expected result? It is not clear how "continuous occurrence" is defined in the case of `groupby`...

Comment: Also, if there is more than one streak of 5 or more values >= 0.5 in the same group, do you add them together to get the total count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the source DataFrame I took:

```
      x    y    z    n
0   0.1  1.0  1.0  1.0
1   0.5  1.0  1.0  1.0
2   0.6  1.0  1.0  1.0
3   0.7  1.0  1.0  1.0
4   0.6  1.0  1.0  1.0
5   0.5  1.0  1.0  1.0
6   0.1  1.0  1.0  1.0
7   0.5  1.0  1.0  1.0
8   0.6  1.0  1.0  1.0
9   0.7  1.0  1.0  1.0
10  0.1  1.0  1.0  1.0
11  0.5  1.0  1.0  1.0
12  0.6  1.0  1.0  1.0
13  0.7  1.0  1.0  1.0
14  0.7  1.0  1.0  1.0
15  0.6  1.0  1.0  1.0
16  0.5  1.0  1.0  1.0
17  0.1  1.0  1.0  1.0
18  0.5  2.0  1.0  1.0
19  0.6  2.0  1.0  1.0
20  0.7  2.0  1.0  1.0
21  0.6  2.0  1.0  1.0
22  0.5  2.0  1.0  1.0
```

(one group for (*y*, *z*, *n*) == (*1.0*, *1.0*, *1.0*) and another for (*2.0*, *1.0*, *1.0*)).

Start from `import itertools as it`.

Then define the following function to get the count of your "wanted"
elements from the current group:

```
def getCnt(grp):
    return sum(filter(lambda x: x >= 5, [ len(list(group))
        for key, group in it.groupby(grp.x, lambda elem: elem >= 0.5)
            if key ]))
```

Note that it contains *it.groupby*, i.e. *groupby* function from *itertools*
(not the *pandasonic* version of it).

The difference is that the *itertools* version starts a new group on each change
of the grouping key (by default, the value of the source element).

Steps:

- `it.groupby(grp.x, lambda elem: elem >= 0.5)` - create an iterator,
  returning pairs (*key*, *group*), from *x* column of the current group.
  The *key* states whether the current group (from *itertools* grouping)
  contains your "wanted" elements (>= 0.5) and the *group* contains these
  elements.
- `[ len(list(group)) for key, group in … if key ]` - get a list of
  lengths of groups, excluding groups of "smaller" elements.
- `filter(lambda x: x >= 5, …)` - filter the above list, leaving only counts
  of groups with 5 or more members.
- `sum(…)` - sum the above counts.

Then, to get your expected result, as a DataFrame, apply this function to
each group of rows, this time grouping with the *pandasonic* version of
*groupby*.

Then set the name of the resulting *Series* (it will be the column name
in the final result) and reset the index, to convert it to a DataFrame.

The code to do it is:

```
result = df.groupby(['y','z','n']).apply(getCnt).rename('Cnt').reset_index()
```

The result is:

```
     y    z    n  Cnt
0  1.0  1.0  1.0   11
1  2.0  1.0  1.0    5
```